# Error running PowerShell Command from Python Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

When I try to run following python PowerShell command:

```
p1 = subprocess.run(
    ['powershell',
     '-Command',
     'Add-DistributionGroupMember -identity "Staff" -member "eng.hassan"'],
    capture_output=True)
```

I got following error:

`'Add-DistributionGroupMember' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Other PowerShell commands executed successfully like (`Get-ADUser`), I think the error cause this command is part of Exchange Online module not the Active Directory commands.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Is the error only happening when you run the PowerShell command in Python? If so, could the problem be that PowerShell is running from a different environment?

Comment: BTW, welcome back to SO! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. Do you just want to ask why the error is occurring, or do you also want help solving it? What research have you done? What have you tried? For example, have you tried [loading the PowerShell module explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps#step-1-load-the-exchange-online-powershell-module)? For more tips, see [ask]. Please [edit] to clarify.